# Solving $\sin 2x = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I don't understand how to solve this type of problems and I'm stuck. I've done:

$$\sin 2x = \frac{-1}{\sqrt[]{2}} \Rightarrow 2\sin x\cos x = \frac{-1}{\sqrt[]{2}} \Rightarrow 2\left(\cos (\frac{\pi}{2}-x)\right)\cos x = \frac{-1}{\sqrt[]{2}} \Rightarrow 2\left( \cos(\frac{\pi}{2})\cos x +\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}) \sin x  \right)\cos x = \frac{-1}{\sqrt[]{2}}$$

If I eval. the left hand side (LHS) of the last step, I get back to the LHS of step 2: $2\sin x\cos x$.

Comment: Are you trying to find all solutions or just one?

Comment: what exactly is the Problem here?

Comment: $\sin2x=\sin(-\pi/4)$ and $$\sin y=\sin A\implies y=n\pi+(-1)^nA$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice $\displaystyle \sin{w}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ when $\displaystyle w=\frac{7π}{4}+2πn$  or $\displaystyle \frac{5π}{4} + 2πn$ using the unit circle.

Substituting $w=2x$, we see $\displaystyle \boxed{x=\frac{7π}{8}+πn}$ or $\displaystyle \boxed{x=\frac{5π}{8}+πn}$.

Comment: I think on the second one you mean to say $+\pi n$ instead of $+2\pi n$?

Comment: oh yeah sorry oops @Frpzzd

Answer (score 2):

HINT: set $$t=2x$$ and solve the equation $$\sin(t)=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, try substitution. If you let $u=2x$, then you get
$$\sin u=-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$
And then the general solution is
$$u=\frac{3\pi}{2}\pm\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi n$$
where $n$ is some integer. Then, when we substitute back $u=2x$, we get
$$2x=\frac{3\pi}{2}\pm\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi n$$
$$x=\frac{3\pi}{4}\pm\frac{\pi}{8}+\pi n$$
And that is the general solution.